# Creating a serializer that only list objects related to user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to make a serializer that only list Groups that the user is related to.

My `User` model have a `group` field with manytomany relations to the `Group` model.

And I want the `GroupSerializer` to only list the groups that the user is related to.

This is my serializer now.

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

It's being called from this serializer for Posting in a group.

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = GroupSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['user', 'post', 'group']
```

My models.:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             verbose_name=_("invited_user"),
                             related_name='invited_user',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group= models.ForeignKey(Group,
                             verbose_name=_('invited_group'),
                             related_name='invited_group',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField(_("Description"), blank=True)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    group = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_("group"),
        blank=True)
```

My viewset:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):        
        return self.queryset.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

As it is now, all groups from the db is available. I only want the ones related to the user.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

You precised you were talking about nested serializer, you need to use the `source` attribute of the SerializerMethodField.

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = SerializerMethodField(source='get_groups', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['user', 'post', 'group']

    def get_groups(self):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        user = request.user
        return GroupSerializer(Group.objects.filter(user=user), many=True).data
```

That requires you passed the request object to the serializer via the context. If you don't know how to do that, there are a lot of SO questions about that.

---

#### Initial answer, before you precised you were talking about nested serializers

The query logic (here filtering on the user) belongs to the view, not to the serializer.

I don't have information about your views.py but the minimal code to get a list of Groups based on the current user could be:

```
# views.py
from rest_framework import generics

class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Group.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: I am not calling the GroupSerializer from a view. I'm calling it from another serializer.

Comment: I've tried that now and it's not working at all. When I declare the SerializerMethodField, the field in the browser disappears. I tried removing the 'filter' and doing an 'all()'. But it doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232565/discussion-between-sumpen-and-guillaume).